# How to remove an option from select based on previous selection,in custom select?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two js:

one, for custom select
https://codepen.io/wallaceerick/pen/ctsCz

```
$('select').each(function(){
var $this = $(this), numberOfOptions = $(this).children('option').length;

$this.addClass('select-hidden'); 
$this.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');
$this.after('<div class="select-styled"></div>');

var $styledSelect = $this.next('div.select-styled');
$styledSelect.text($this.children('option').eq(0).text());

var $list = $('<ul />', {
    'class': 'select-options'
}).insertAfter($styledSelect);

for (var i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
    $('<li />', {
        text: $this.children('option').eq(i).text(),
        rel: $this.children('option').eq(i).val()
    }).appendTo($list);
}

var $listItems = $list.children('li');

$styledSelect.click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('div.select-styled.active').not(this).each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('active').next('ul.select-options').hide();
    });
    $(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul.select-options').toggle();
});

$listItems.click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $styledSelect.text($(this).text()).removeClass('active');
    $this.val($(this).attr('rel'));
    $list.hide();
    //console.log($this.val());
});

$(document).click(function() {
    $styledSelect.removeClass('active');
    $list.hide();
});
});
```

the second, for removing an option from select that was already selected in a previous select menu http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/vrLr9wyg/

```
var $dropdown1 = $("select[name='dropdown1']");
var $dropdown2 = $("select[name='dropdown2']");

$dropdown1.change(function() {
    $dropdown2.empty().append($dropdown1.find('option').clone());
    var selectedItem = $(this).val();
    if (selectedItem) {
        $dropdown2.find('option[value="' + selectedItem + '"]').remove();
    }
});
```

both work fine separately, but i can't incorporate the second in the first
how could i make them work?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to combine apples and oranges. Can you be more specific about the behavior needed?

Comment: i have two select menus with same options. i want, once i choose one option from the first, to be removed from the second. 
it works fine but if the select is not customized 
@charlietfl

Comment: So you now only need to remove from customized one?

Comment: yes @charlietfl

Comment: is it possible to show the chosen option once the menu is open? as [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_custom_select) @charlietfl

Comment: Sure it's possible, you already have an example of it

Comment: but the 'js' in the example given, is different from the 'js' posted in the first question

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you break down your idea into smaller tasks:

you have two sets of data, and they are represented with two `select` elements. If you select an item from the first dataset, then it shouldn't be selectable from the second dataset.

The easiest way (I think) is to keep track of the selected items in a third object, and filter you options based on data stored there.

```js
// two option arrays
const optArr1 = [
  "opt1",
  "opt2",
  "opt3",
  "opt4",
]

const optArr2 = [
  "opt1",
  "opt2",
  "opt3",
  "opt4",
]

// an object to keep track of selections
const selected = {
  first: null,
  second: null,
}

// add options
const addOptions = (optArr) => {
  let html = ''
  optArr.forEach(opt => {
    html += `<option value="${ opt }">${ opt }</option>`
  })
  return html
}

// updating displays - only needed for debugging
const updateDisplays = (selected) => {
  $('#firstSelect').html(selected.first)

  // filtering the second select's options:
  $('#second').html(addOptions(optArr2.filter(e => e !== selected.first)))
  $('#secondSelect').html(selected.second)
  $('#rawObject').html(JSON.stringify(selected))
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // init displays
  $('#first').html(addOptions(optArr1))
  $('#second').html(addOptions(optArr2))
  $('#rawObject').html(JSON.stringify(selected))

  // click first select
  $('#first').on('input', function(e) {
    selected.first = e.target.value
    selected.second = null
    updateDisplays(selected)
  })

  // click second select
  $('#second').on('input', function(e) {
    selected.second = e.target.value
    updateDisplays(selected)
  })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="first"></select>
<select id="second"></select>
<hr />
<div>
  FIRST SELECT: <span id="firstSelect"></span>
</div><br />
<div>
  SECOND SELECT: <span id="secondSelect"></span>
</div><br />
<div>
  THE RAW SELECTED OBJECT: <span id="rawObject"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: it works on its own, not with a customized dropdown (first js attached)

Comment: @bahdah sorry, but I don't get the meaning of your comment.

Comment: the script you gave does not work when i customize the dropdown menu using the following js  [link](https://codepen.io/wallaceerick/pen/ctsCz)